# Android Studio. App stops Working and IDE showing no errors?

Tags: android, compilation, runtime

I'm exporting an App and running it directly to my Android phone. The app doesn't even run and Android system shows this error: "App stopped working". Android Studio shows no errors or warnings... Why?

Comment: LogCat in Android Studio has its issues. Try changing the drop-down from `app: ...` (for whatever your application ID is) to "No Filters" and see if your stack trace shows up.

Comment: Has to be an error of some type, what does your logcat show?

Comment: Thanks to both, It was a "cache" error. Restarted cache in Android Studio and everything worked fine. I guess Google has to work harder on that kind of mistakes...